# Missing StrokeThickness on MapPolyline of Bing.Maps Windows 8

Tags: dictionary, bing, stroke

I use polyline to draw circle on Bing Maps (Metro App) but it appears aliasing on Maps, it's not smooth.
I think it does not have strokethickness.

How can I solve?
Thanks

```
    MapShapeLayer shapeLayer = new MapShapeLayer();
    MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
    polyline.Locations = DrawMapsCircle(location, 1000);

    polyline.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
    polyline.Width = 1;

    shapeLayer.Shapes.Add(polyline);

    maps.ShapeLayers.Add(shapeLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the width of the polyline

```
polyline.Width = 5;
```